# Date format changing after reload page in rails 4 using datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, date, ruby-on-rails-4, datetimepicker

I've noticed something strange in my app.

When I enter to the main page here:
http://leszczyna.wzks.uj.edu.pl/12_stolarski/events_for_seniors/
and click on the second field in search and pick something, the date format appearing is '**dd-mm-yyyy**'.

But when I click in the top left-hand corner 'Wydarzenia dla seniorów' date format is changing to '**dd/mm/yyyy**'. 
I've noticed that locale is appearing in URL but have no idea if it has impact on that behavior.

What is more, when I refresh page after that, date format comes to the beginning.

What can cause that strange behavior of that input?

**EDIT**

Code from my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only" for="date">Email</label>
      <%= text_field_tag :date,
                         params[:date],
                         placeholder: 'Kliknij, aby wybrać datę',
                         class: 'form-control input-lg date',
                         :data => {
                                 provide: 'datepicker'
                         }
      %>
    </div>
```

And my javascript:

```
    /* Search date */
if ($('body.homepage').length) {
    $('.date').datepicker({
        'language': "pl",
        'todayHighlight': true,
        'format': 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        'autoclose': true
    })
}
```

Comment: Paste your view code

Comment: paste your jQuery code for adding datepicker to date field

Comment: what is the value of params[:date]?

Comment: do you have `config/locale/pl.yml` file? if yes, then can you post the content of that file too? if it's too big then probably the part which has date should be sufficient

Comment: @user123
When it's the first case 'dd-mm-yyyy' it's for example 'date: 14-05-2015'
When second. 'dd/mm/yyyy' it's 'date: 05/14/2015'

Comment: @Surya
My pl.yml

`pl:
  layouts:
    application:
      app_name: "Wydarzenia dla seniorów"
    navbar:
      app_name: "Wydarzenia dla seniorów"`

Comment: Put this in your View and try.
`<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#date").datepicker({
      'language': "pl",
      'todayHighlight': true,
      'format': 'dd-mm-yyyy',
      'autoclose': true
    })
  });
</script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening due to `turbolinks`, turn off `turbolinks` for the top left-hand corner 'Wydarzenia dla seniorów' link. In the header your link is present under a div with `navbar-header` class. To that div element add `data-no-turbolink`, example below

```
<div class="navbar-header" data-no-turbolink>
```

This will resolve your problem!

**or**

In your js file, load javascript like this

```
ready = function(){

  /* Search date */
  if ($('body.homepage').length) {
    $('.date').datepicker({
        'language': "pl",
        'todayHighlight': true,
        'format': 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        'autoclose': true
    });
  }  
}
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

This is the best solution.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @RSB, can you look at my new search form? I've made it to change date or city, but datepicker doesn't work properly, again. 
Here is link:

http://leszczyna.wzks.uj.edu.pl/12_stolarski/events_for_seniors/pl/events?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Krak%C3%B3w&start_date=11-06-2015

Problem is with datepicker, when you click on it it changes to another format and year is set to 1911. Maybe I need to add no-turbolinks somewhere?

I've added to my js your solution, changed body.homepage to body.events, but it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

By adding following code in your form will resolve your problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $( document ).ready(function() { 
    $("#date").datepicker({ 
      'language': "pl",
      'todayHighlight': true,
      'format': 'dd-mm-yyyy',
      'autoclose': true
    }) 
  }); 
</script>
```