# Datepicker change date value and formatting rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I've made form to change date or city, but datepicker doesn't work properly. Here is link: http://leszczyna.wzks.uj.edu.pl/12_stolarski/events_for_seniors/pl/events?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Krak%C3%B3w&start_date=11-06-2015

Problem is with datepicker, when you click on it, it changes date to another format and year is set to 1911.

**Here is my js:**

```
$('document').ready(function() {
if ($('body.events').length) {
  /* Datepicker for changing date in events */
    $('.date').datepicker({
        'language': "pl",
        'todayHighlight': true,
        'format': 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        'autoclose': true
    })
}
```

**And part of my erb file**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="date">Email</label>
        <%= text_field_tag :start_date,
                           params[:start_date],
                           placeholder: 'Kliknij, aby wybrać datę',
                           class: 'form-control date',
                           :data => {
                                   provide: 'datepicker'
                           }
        %>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have kept your format as `dd-mm-yyyy`, but your param `:start_date` holds value in wrong order. If you want to set come default date, I will suggest you to use `defaultViewDate` option. Your calendar dates (which opens up initially) are disabled, that's why it selects some 1911 year date. try using `startDate` and `endDate` option. I hope it will fix it.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer. I've changed params[:start_date] format and now default date loads properly. But if you click on input, calendar view is set to November 2015 and formatting is still wrong. I had similar issue earlier, here is link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30477864/date-format-changing-after-reload-page-in-rails-4-using-datetimepicker/30479027#30479027
and disabling turbolinks helped. Maybe I need to disable turbolinks also here? But I have no idea, where it need to be done.

Comment: I believe it doesn't understands `-` sign as separator. So, its taking default format of date i.e. mm/dd/yyyy. Kindly change format from dd-mm-yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy. Rest your calendar works find now.

Comment: I tried it locally, and it also doesn't understand `/` sign.

Comment: Had you used `defaultViewDate` option?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late answer. Do you mean option in datepicker in js file? In documentation there is only defaultDate option. I used it like that `'defaultDate' : new Date()` and `'defaultDate' : '15-06-2015'`. Nothing worked. I think it doesn't load the js, cause I've got for example `'language': "pl"` but there are english names.

Comment: Ok, I made it :D instead of `$('document').ready(function() ` should be `$(document).on('page:load', function()`, the problem was beacause turbolinks. Thanks a lot for help!